# AnimationEnd is triggered on all View at once

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an application with 3 Image Buttons (based on the custom image button) this image button has an animation end listened, once the First Image Button completes animation, all instances of this Custom Images Buttons Trigger the AnimationEnd method.

Here's my Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

class MyImageButton extends ImageButton{

    protected Callable<Void> AnimEnd = null;
    public void setOnAnimationEndListener(Callable<Void> AnimEnd1) {
        this.AnimEnd = AnimEnd1;
    }


    public MyImageButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAnimationEnd() {
        super.onAnimationEnd();
        //Functionality here
        if(this.AnimEnd != null){
            try{
                this.AnimEnd.call();
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Notice the 3 Image Buttons animate with Offset 2 Seconds (2000 msec) away from Each other.**

I set a callback for image Button as follows:

```
object1.setOnAnimationEndListener(new Callable<Void>() {

            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {

                object1.setAnimation(null);
                object1.setLayoutParams(params);

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });

// Similarly object2, object3 all of them are instances of MyImageButton
```

Comment: how u know it is getting fired for those three buttons ?

Comment: Share the code where you run the animations

Comment: @Triode I log a line to make sure

Comment: @Sean. As simple as. TransitionalAnimation ta1 = new TransitionalAnimation (.....); then setDuration and offset then object1.startAnimation ( ta1 ); then the last code as above

Comment: @Shehabix Sorry, can't help